# SwifiUI json error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5c8)."

Tags: json

I'm learning SwiftUI and try to modify code

What I did is changed data definitions and types in json and I got error which I can't figure it out why I got this error.
working from Playground project.
this code is working

```
import UIKit

let json = """
{
"ROWID": "2",
"Brand": "Brand Here",
"ProductCode": "Product Code here" ,
"Description" : "Product Description here",
"WHCode" : "01",
"Loc":"01",
"QTY" : 24,
"Unit":"pcs",
"Cost":24.0
}
"""
struct Stock: Codable {
    var ROWID: String
    var Brand: String
    var ProductCode: String
    var Description : String
    var WHCode : String
    var Loc : String
    //experiment try to change QTY from INT to string
    var QTY : Int
    var Unit : String
    var Cost : Double
    
   // var Price : String
}
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8) {
do {
let stock = try decoder.decode(Stock.self, from: jsonData)
    print(stock)
    } catch {
        print(error)
} }
```

but when I just changed only data type for QTY from int to String I've got error.

**"error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
"**

```
import UIKit

let json = """
{
"ROWID": "2",
"Brand": "Brand Here",
"ProductCode": "Product Code here" ,
"Description" : "Product Description here",
"WHCode" : "01",
"Loc":"01",
"QTY" : "24",
"Unit":"pcs",
"Cost":24.0
}
"""
struct Stock: Codable {
    var ROWID: String
    var Brand: String
    var ProductCode: String
    var Description : String
    var WHCode : String
    var Loc : String
    //experiment try to change QTY from INT to string
    var QTY : String
    var Unit : String
    var Cost : Double
    
   // var Price : String
}
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8) {
do {
let stock = try decoder.decode(Stock.self, from: jsonData)
    print(stock)
    } catch {
        print(error)
} }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce .. not crashing for me